# union of two queries to get the result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm confused about this:

```
SELECT request_id, SUM( cc_amount ) AS amt,
       DATE_FORMAT( transaction_datetime,  '%b %y' ) AS tdate
  FROM ee_request_cc
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( transaction_datetime,  '%b %y' ) 

UNION 

SELECT request_id, SUM( request_amount ) AS amt,
       DATE_FORMAT( transaction_date,  '%b %y' ) AS tdate
  FROM ee_request_paypal
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( transaction_date,  '%b %y' )
```

I'm getting:

```
id    amt    tdate
20  86.00   Mar 12
80   5.00   Apr 12
23  55.00   Mar 12
```

Whereas I want to add all amounts for March and April like:

```
id     amt   tdate
20  141.00  Mar 12
80    5.00  Apr 12
```

Please suggest me the change in my query.

Comment: Just use `GROUP BY tr_date` and `GROUP BY transaction_dt`.

Comment: As shown by Gavin in his answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the results, and then perform the aggregation:

```
SELECT table_both.request_id, table_both.tdate, SUM(table_both.amount) AS amt
FROM (SELECT request_id, cc_amount AS amt, DATE_FORMAT(transaction_datetime,'%b %y') AS tdate
    FROM table1 

    UNION ALL --Don't remove the duplicates

    SELECT request_id, request_amount, DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%b %y')
    FROM table2) table_both
GROUP BY table_both.request_id, table_both.tdate --You don't need to add the format function in the group by
```

Comment: Can you please check my latest code and write your updated code accordingly. because i'm getting error in your code.

Comment: The choice of 'all' as the query alias is perhaps not the best choice; it is a keyword too, as you showed.  Maybe 'AS all' would work better?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, good point. I have updated the query, try again fawad.

Comment: Unknown column 'table_both.cc_amount' in 'field list'... something wrong with table_both

Comment: It is printing all the values day by day instead of Group by month

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(amt), DATE_FORMAT(tdate, '%b %y') from (
    SELECT amount1 AS amt, transaction_dt AS tdate
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT request_amount, tr_date
    FROM table2
) s
GROUP BY YEAR(tdate), MONTH(tdate)
```

Note you shouldn't take an ID from a grouped result... which one would you take?

Also grouping by numbers must be faster than transforming a date to a string and then grouping by string.

Comment: It could be that the ID needs to be grouped on, it could always be a foreign key instead of a primary key.

Comment: @GavinCattell You shouldn't call `ID` a foreign key. Not to mention that if you group by `ID` and also the date field you are assuming all `ID`s for that month have the same value. If they don't you'll get more than one row per month/year pair

Comment: If you must have 'an ID' in the result, then make it an aggregate - either MIN(id) or MAX(id) makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You use an englobing SELECT with sum on amt and GROUP BY tdate

```
SELECT id, SUM(amt) as samt, tdate
FROM (YOUR_ABOBE_QUERY) AS thequery
GROUP BY thequery.tdate
```